# Display bank account number using format-number() function

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, string-formatting

I have an example bank account number:

```
06101010100075911391740027
```

I want to display it as followed:

```
06 1010 1010 0075 9113 9174 0027
```

I tried following piece of code:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="&#160;"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(06101010100075911391740027,'##&#160;####&#160;####&#160;####&#160;####&#160;####&#160;0000','european')"/>
```

But the result was far from expected:

> 6 1010 1010 0075 9110 0000 0000

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have leading zeros, you would need to use the 0 digit symbol rather than #:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(06101010100075911391740027,
        '00&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000','european')"/>
```

However this still results in a string of 9 zeros at the end, due to floating-point rounding. Do you have this number actually being passed around as a number in your XSLT, or is it a string value? If it's a string value, you can just use concat() and substring():

```
<xsl:variable name="an" select="'06101010100075911391740027'" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($an, 1, 2), '&#160;',
                             substring($an, 3, 4), '&#160;',
                             substring($an, 7, 4), '&#160;',
                             substring($an, 11, 4), '&#160;',
                             substring($an, 15, 4), '&#160;',
                             substring($an, 19, 4), '&#160;',
                             substring($an, 23, 4))" />
```

If it really is being handled as a number datatype, I think your only option may be to change your approach to handle it as a string instead.

Comment: Okey, but why rounding (as You said) omits the last 9 digits?

Comment: @tytan It's because, as indicated in the [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers), numbers are represented as 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 values, which provide [15-17 digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) of precision. Your number is being output with its first 16 digits, and the left are treated as zero because the datatype can't represent precision further than that.

Comment: the correct a answer is above and is to treat it as a string. Afterall, that is what it really is. It is not a number although it is represented by digits. you would never do math functions against it. it is a string of digits.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `#` in `format-number()` means that **there could be** a number on that position. But instead of `#` you can also use `0`, which means that on that position **should always be** a number. If no number found it will display a 0.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(06101010100075911391740027,'00&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160;0000&#160')"/>
```

Above should give you the correct result.

Comment: I cant use zeros, becasue there are zeros passed to result, as mentioned in other ansewer...